# pushing "distinct" into PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

A re-write to make it easier to understand.

Parse's PFQueryTableViewController tracks downloaded objects in an "objects" NSArray that is set readonly. I can remove Parse's readonly attribute manually and let this happen, but wondered if this might impact other areas.

*This is likely not a great SO question, but perfectly suited for proper forums, which Parse decided against, which is too bad.

=====original text
I am trying to organize distinctness in parse data delivery since parse seems to not be interested in this. I think we need to realize that this type of data NEVER needs to be used for edits given that it is at summary level. ID's within the data can easily be used to open details of other records though, and this is my primary use-case.

So my thinking was simple: grab my original parse data that contains dups. Hit objectsDidLoad: and walk the objects, add each to a NSMutableDictionary if the key is not yet found, and when done, reset the objects array, but it is read-only.

**So, my question to more experienced parse guys:** If i simply hit PFQueryTableViewController and edit away the read-only attribute, does anyone foresee this being damaging? I prefer to continue using PFQueryTableViewController rather than the regular VC.

Comment: The way you've worded your question makes it very difficult to understand what you're asking...

Comment: thanks Lyndsey, i have reworked it a bit to see if i can do better..